# How to remove not installed application on Android

Tags: android

Before I release new version of app I always test upgrade process on device. What I do is I uninstall application I use to debug, go to market, download old version. Then install new APK using adb tool and see how it upgrades.

Today I was surprised that after I uninstalled my development version and installed market version it still shows higher version number (development)

So.. It seems that it's a new OS feature when you delete app - it goes to the bottom of the list as "NOT INSTALLED". Now, when I go to market it doesn't download old version but instead takes this deleted one and uses it..

Question IS: How do I get rid of "NOT INSTALLED" copy to test upgrade? I use Nexus 7 tablet (no root)

Comment: Are you sure your development app has the same package name as the market version?

Comment: Of course it does. I think OS just installs newer version (development) and never even tries to download because package already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Solved.

When choose application need to click "menu" and choose "uninstall for all users". If you just click "uninstall" button it's not enough. Or maybe enough if there is only 1 user.